# Trying to install spree, but I can't get the database up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, spree

I am working with spree - which is brand new to me. I am following the getting started guide that can be found at [spree- getting started](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html).  Unfortunately whenever i get to step 4.4.2 which tells me to invoke the "rake db:create" command I get the following error. I am stuck, and any help would be so appreciated. Thanks.

```
  C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby192\bin\rake db:create --trace
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: ref is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: new is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.2. (called from <top (required)> at C:/Users/Edu/RubymineProjects/myStore/config/application.rb:7)
    ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
    ** Execute rails_env
    ** Execute db:load_config
    rake aborted!
    syntax error on line 18, col 2: `  host: localhost'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:105:in `database_configuration'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1.rc2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:114:in `invoke_task'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `block in top_level'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `each'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:131:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.3.beta.1/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<top (required)>'
    -e:1:in `load'
    -e:1:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error happens when your  `database.yml` file contain invalid characters, perhaps tabs instead of spaces. Double check this and see if that fixes it.